# Problem with rounding of number

Tags: plotting, calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration, integral-equations

I am evaluating a numerical integral and Mathematica returns several messages such as this one:

```
Round: internal precision limit $MaxExtraPrecision = 50. reached while \
evaluating Round[(1/50 - Sqrt[25001]/50)/(2 (-(1/50) + Sqrt[25001]/50))]
```

What is the problem with this? The argument of `Round` is just 0.5.

Code for replication:

**SYSTEM OF ODEs**

```
OdeM = 1/2*\[Sigma]*V1''[x] + ((a0*\[Delta])/a1 - a1*x)*V1'[x] - em*V1[x] == -((2*x - 2*ep*(a0 + a1*x)* \[Lambda])/(em - ep));
OdeP = 1/2*\[Sigma]*V2''[x] + ((a0*\[Delta])/a1 - a1*x)*V2'[x] - ep*V2[x] == -((-2*x + 2*em*(a0 + a1*x)* \[Lambda])/(em - ep));
```

**BOUNDARY CONDITIONS**

```
Ic1 = em*V1[xhat] + ep*V2[xhat] == 0;
Ic2 = em*V1'[xhat] + ep*V2'[xhat] == 0;
Ic3 = V1[xhat] + V2[xhat] == (2*\[Theta])/((\[Epsilon] - 1) (1 + \[CurlyPhi]))*xhat;
Ic4 = V1'[xhat] + V2'[xhat] == (2*\[Theta])/((\[Epsilon] - 1) (1 + \[CurlyPhi]));
```

**SOLUTION**

```
SolGeneral = DSolve[{OdeM, OdeP, Ic1, Ic2, Ic3, Ic4}, {V1[x], V2[x]}, x] // Simplify
SolGeneral2 = SolGeneral /. Integrate -> Inactive[NIntegrate];
SolV1[x_] = V1[x] /. SolGeneral2[[1]];
SolV2[x_] = V2[x] /. SolGeneral2[[1]];
```

**PARAMETERS**

```
\[Delta] = 1/100;
\[Theta] = 2;
\[Epsilon] = 3/2;
\[CurlyPhi] = 3/2;
\[Xi] = 5/1000;
\[Lambda] = 1/2;
\[Sigma] = (1/5)^2;
\[Mu]A = 3/20;
\[Sigma]A = 1/5;
rn = \[Delta] + \[Mu]A - \[Sigma]A^2;
xhat = 0.05;
em = (\[Delta]*\[Theta] - Sqrt[\[Delta]^2*\[Theta]^2 + 4*\[Theta]*(\[Epsilon] - 1)*(1 + \[CurlyPhi])])/(2*\[Theta]);
ep = (\[Delta]*\[Theta] + Sqrt[\[Delta]^2*\[Theta]^2 + 4*\[Theta]*(\[Epsilon] - 1)*(1 + \[CurlyPhi])])/(2*\[Theta]);
a1 = (-\[Delta]*\[Theta] + Sqrt[\[Delta]^2*\[Theta]^2 + 4*\[Theta]*(\[Epsilon] - 1)*(1 + \[CurlyPhi])])/(2*\[Theta]);
a0 = -((\[Xi] + rn - 1/2*\[Sigma] - \[Sigma]A*Sqrt[\[Sigma]])/(\[Delta] + a1))*a1;
```

**PLOTTING**

```
Plot[Activate[SolV1[x]], {x, -0.1, 0.05}]
```

Comment: I'm not sure what the cause is, but you can get the same error from Round[(1/50 - Sqrt[25001]/50)/(2 (-(1/50) + Sqrt[25001]/50))]. Observe the error goes away if you use floating point numbers: Round[(1/50. - Sqrt[25001]/50)/(2 (-(1/50) + Sqrt[25001]/50))] (I just changed "50" to "50.") So maybe try using floating point numbers instead of exact in the NIntegrate.